# Branch.io does not work with multidex because of manifest conflict

Tags: android, branch.io, android-multidex

Branch wants me to use the "android:name" in the manifests file, but I already use it for multidex. So, how to overcome this conflict?

```
<application
    ...
    //android:name="io.branch.referral.BranchApp"
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    ...
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the entire code of BranchApp:

```
public class BranchApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        if (BranchUtil.isTestModeEnabled(this) == false) {
            Branch.getInstance(this);
        } else {
            Branch.getTestInstance(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Make a custom Application class that extends MultiDexApplication, and use this override for the onCreate and you're good.

Answer (score 0):

The Branch SDK has its own custom activity and application class. Other plugins that use their own custom activity and application classes can cause "conflicts" between these classes. To resolve these conflicts:

1. Create an empty android library
2. Add the Branch plugin along with the other plugins into your project
3. Create a custom Activity and Application class that will contain the custom logic for all your plugins
4. Build your library
5. Add your library into Unity project
6. Change android:name to name of your custom Application class in the application tag of your Manifest
7. Change android:name to name of your custom Activity class in the activity tag of your Manifest

Some Plugins expand the default AppController the same was as Branch does like Cardboard SDK plugin. To resolve conflicts:

1. Merge all custom AppControllers in one.
2. Comment code in other AppControllers (or delete other AppControllers).

Here are some [Code Samples](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/unity-branch-deep-linking/tree/master/ThirdPartySolutions) for resolving conflicts with other 3rd party plugins

If you still face any issues, please write to integrations@branch.io with the details.